# Trying to destroy prefab upon collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-editor, prefab

I'm making a `3D` Unity game and trying to get randomly-spawned prefabs disappear when they collide with the player object, but I'm not sure why it isn't working.

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("target"))
    {
        score.Value += 1;
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I've dragged the script into the player object, and the prefab looks like this:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz9OU.png)]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: is the box collider larger than the capsule collider?

Comment: you dont want to destroy a prefab, you want to destroy the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have both the `BoxCollider` and a `CapsuleCollider` attached. Try removing or disabling the `CapsuleCollider` to check if this is the case

If everything looks okay, just add some `print("Collided")` to the function to check if it even detects the collision. Maybe there are other scripts that iterfere with this. I once had a problem that two `OnCollisionEnter()` scripts needed to destroy each other, but only one got destroyed.

Hope this helps!